# Usage of typescript infer does not work for array

Tags: arrays, typescript, type-inference

I have the following typescript code:

```
const myObject = {
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}

type MyType = typeof myObject.foo extends [...infer Content] ? string : boolean
```

And MyType results in type `string` as expected.

But if I change the code like this:

```
...

type MyType = typeof myObject.foo extends [infer First, ...infer Tail] ? string : boolean
```

MyType now becomes `boolean`. Why?

Why does it extend in the first case but not in the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First use case:**

```js
const myObject = {
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}

type MyType1 = string[] extends [...infer Content] ? string : boolean
```

`[...infer Content]` - means that tuple might have 0 or 1 or more elements. No restriction at all.

Hence, since `string[]` is an array without explicit length (is not a tuple) you are getting `string`.

**Second case**

```js
type MyType2 = string[] extends [infer First, ...infer Tail] ? string : boolean
```

`[infer First, ...infer Tail]` - mean that your tuple should have at least one element, because of `First`.
Because you are checking `myObject.foo` which is basically `stirng[]`, TS is not allowed to make any assumptions about `string[]` length. `string[]` is a mutable array.

Try to make `myObject` immutable.

```js
const myObject = {
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c']
} as const;

// string
type MyType1 = typeof myObject.foo extends readonly [...infer Content] ? string : boolean
//string
type MyType2 = typeof myObject.foo extends readonly [infer First, ...infer Tail] ? string : boolean
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAsAFAwwBmIIAXDANoDkAhgwDQwMpsfAMC6JAL4wmEGKEhQA3CRIB6OTGgAnAJZgA5iSgIADhhgBZBABU9GAIww8O-SHLxk6LFAB0lEDAwAPKBjAAJmLKGEwB4AA2CPSuserkGMowAMLgfmBQfDAA-EpQapowtChUEaFg8nIq6lrEtgbGZvoATNYw9faOqJjY7lRevv5BMCFhkdF08YkwAGKqytDssa5TSSZMqhFZudWFxaXlJEA)

Now, both `MyType`'s are `strings`.

**SUMMARY**

`['a', 'b', 'c']` is infered as `string[]` because, like I said it is an array and not a tuple.

If you want it to make a tuple, you can use `['a', 'b', 'c'] as const`.